# Not able to populate table dynamic row using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am working on a project wherein I am reading from a spreadsheet using Python `selenium` and then filling in a web application.  The target web application is made using angular. While I am able to target most of the fields there is one dynamic table (image attached) which  I am not able to target using Python `selenium`. This is dynamic table means - user can add a new row to fill in his language proficiency. In the spreadsheet we have added columns containing data to represent user choices.

The code shared below fills in the first row and adds a new row, but is unable to fill in second to possibly 5th row. The code should add 4 more rows (provided data is present in  `dataframe`). I tried using variable "next_row" both inside as well as outside the for loop but it was of no avail.

```
language_container = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located(
                    (By.XPATH, "//table//tbody[@formarrayname='langauagesArray']")))
    language_rows = WebDriverWait(language_container, 30).until(
                    expected_conditions.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,".//tr")))
    
                for i, row in enumerate(language_rows):
                    try:
                        language_input = row.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//input[@formcontrolname='language']")

                        print(language_input)
                        if pd.notnull(item[f'natural_lang{i + 1}']):
                            language_input.send_keys(item[f'natural_lang{i + 1}'])
                            print(item[f'natural_lang{i + 1}'])
                        # else:
                        #     continue
    
                        read = item[f'read{i + 1}']
                        print('read', read)
                        read_checkbox = WebDriverWait(row, 10).until(
                            expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, ".//input[@formcontrolname='read']"))
                        )
                        if read:
                            read_checkbox.click()
    
                        write = item[f'write{i + 1}']
                        write_checkbox = WebDriverWait(row, 10).until(
                            expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, ".//input[@formcontrolname='write']"))
                        )
                        if write:
                            write_checkbox.click()
    
                        speak = item[f'speak{i + 1}']
                        speak_checkbox = WebDriverWait(row, 10).until(
                            expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, ".//input[@formcontrolname='speak']"))
                        )
                        print('speak',speak)
                        if speak:
                            speak_checkbox.click()
                        self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[normalize-space()='Add row']").click()
                        time.sleep(randint(2, 3))
                        next_row_index = i + 1
                        next_row_xpath = f"//tbody[@formarrayname='langauagesArray']/tr[{next_row_index + 1}]"
                        next_row = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
                            expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, next_row_xpath))
                        )
    
                    except NoSuchElementException as e:
                        logger.error(f'error at adding natural language row: {e}')
                        #next_row_index = i + 1
                        #next_row_xpath = f"//tbody[@formarrayname='langauagesArray']/tr[{next_row_index + 1}]"
                        #next_row = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
                            #expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, next_row_xpath))
                        #)
```

The `dom` of the target website is shared below for your reference:

```
<table
            _ngcontent-pot-c192=""
            cellpadding="0"
            cellspacing="0"
            class="uploadTable table"
        >
            <thead _ngcontent-pot-c192="">
                <tr _ngcontent-pot-c192="">
                    <th _ngcontent-pot-c192="" class="TabHead">
                        <label _ngcontent-pot-c192="" class="Label"
                            >Language</label
                        >
                    </th>
                    <th _ngcontent-pot-c192="" class="TabHead">
                        <label _ngcontent-pot-c192="" class="Label">Read</label>
                    </th>
                    <th _ngcontent-pot-c192="" class="TabHead">
                        <label _ngcontent-pot-c192="" class="Label"
                            >Write</label
                        >
                    </th>
                    <th _ngcontent-pot-c192="" class="TabHead">
                        <label _ngcontent-pot-c192="" class="Label"
                            >Speak</label
                        >
                    </th>
                    <th
                        _ngcontent-pot-c192=""
                        class="TabHead ng-star-inserted"
                        style=""
                    >
                        <label _ngcontent-pot-c192="" class="Label"></label>
                    </th>
                    <!---->
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody
                _ngcontent-pot-c192=""
                formarrayname="langauagesArray"
                class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid"
            >
                <tr
                    _ngcontent-pot-c192=""
                    class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid ng-star-inserted"
                >
                    <td _ngcontent-pot-c192="" class="TabCol">
                        <div
                            _ngcontent-pot-c192=""
                            style="text-align: center; display: flex"
                        >
                            <input
                                _ngcontent-pot-c192=""
                                formcontrolname="language"
                                type="text"
                                autocomplete="off"
                                mattooltip="type here minimum 3 characters"
                                tabindex="2"
                                class="mat-tooltip-trigger mat-autocomplete-trigger form-control form-control-sm ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid"
                                role="combobox"
                                aria-autocomplete="list"
                                aria-expanded="false"
                                aria-haspopup="true"
                                aria-describedby="cdk-describedby-message-10"
                                cdk-describedby-host=""
                            />
                            <!---->
                            <mat-autocomplete
                                _ngcontent-pot-c192=""
                                class="mat-autocomplete"
                                ><!----></mat-autocomplete
                            >
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td
                        _ngcontent-pot-c192=""
                        class="TabCol"
                        style="text-align: center"
                    >
                        <input
                            _ngcontent-pot-c192=""
                            type="checkbox"
                            formcontrolname="read"
                            value="true"
                            class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid"
                        />
                    </td>
                    <td
                        _ngcontent-pot-c192=""
                        class="TabCol"
                        style="text-align: center"
                    >
                        <input
                            _ngcontent-pot-c192=""
                            type="checkbox"
                            formcontrolname="write"
                            value="true"
                            class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid"
                        />
                    </td>
                    <td
                        _ngcontent-pot-c192=""
                        class="TabCol"
                        style="text-align: center"
                    >
                        <input
                            _ngcontent-pot-c192=""
                            type="checkbox"
                            formcontrolname="speak"
                            value="true"
                            class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid"
                        />
                    </td>
                    <td
                        _ngcontent-pot-c192=""
                        class="TabCol ng-star-inserted"
                        style="text-align: center"
                    >
                        <a
                            _ngcontent-pot-c192=""
                            style="
                                text-decoration: underline;
                                color: blue;
                                cursor: pointer;
                            "
                            >Delete</a
                        >
                    </td>
                    <!---->
                </tr>
                <tr
                    _ngcontent-pot-c192=""
                    class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-star-inserted"
                    style=""
                >
                    <td _ngcontent-pot-c192="" class="TabCol">
                        <div
                            _ngcontent-pot-c192=""
                            style="text-align: center; display: flex"
                        >
                            <input
                                _ngcontent-pot-c192=""
                                formcontrolname="language"
                                type="text"
                                autocomplete="off"
                                mattooltip="type here minimum 3 characters"
                                tabindex="2"
                                class="mat-tooltip-trigger mat-autocomplete-trigger form-control form-control-sm ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid"
                                role="combobox"
                                aria-autocomplete="list"
                                aria-expanded="false"
                                aria-haspopup="true"
                                aria-describedby="cdk-describedby-message-10"
                                cdk-describedby-host=""
                            />
                            <!---->
                            <mat-autocomplete
                                _ngcontent-pot-c192=""
                                class="mat-autocomplete"
                                ><!----></mat-autocomplete
                            >
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td
                        _ngcontent-pot-c192=""
                        class="TabCol"
                        style="text-align: center"
                    >
                        <input
                            _ngcontent-pot-c192=""
                            type="checkbox"
                            formcontrolname="read"
                            value="true"
                            class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid"
                        />
                    </td>
                    <td
                        _ngcontent-pot-c192=""
                        class="TabCol"
                        style="text-align: center"
                    >
                        <input
                            _ngcontent-pot-c192=""
                            type="checkbox"
                            formcontrolname="write"
                            value="true"
                            class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid"
                        />
                    </td>
                    <td
                        _ngcontent-pot-c192=""
                        class="TabCol"
                        style="text-align: center"
                    >
                        <input
                            _ngcontent-pot-c192=""
                            type="checkbox"
                            formcontrolname="speak"
                            value="true"
                            class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid"
                        />
                    </td>
                    <td
                        _ngcontent-pot-c192=""
                        class="TabCol ng-star-inserted"
                        style="text-align: center"
                    >
                        <a
                            _ngcontent-pot-c192=""
                            style="
                                text-decoration: underline;
                                color: blue;
                                cursor: pointer;
                            "
                            >Delete</a
                        >
                    </td>
                    <!---->
                </tr>
                <!---->
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

[image: dynamic table with rows which i need to fill]

Dynamic table with rows which I need to fill.